# How can I check if a function parameter exists with Python?

Tags: python

My code is:

```
def load_data(datafile, categories=None, cat_columns=None):
    ohe_categories = 'auto'
    if categories and len(categories) > 0:
        ohe_categories = categories
    ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', categories=ohe_categories)
```

When `categories` is `None`, it works fine. But if I pass something, I get an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Index is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I am calling the function with:

```
training_x, training_y, categories, cat_columns = loader.load_data(
    'data/training.csv')

test_x, test_y = loader.load_data(
    'data/test.csv', categories=categories, cat_columns=cat_columns)
```

How can I check properly?

Comment: Can add the line of code you use to call the function?

Comment: It appears to be an `Index`

Comment: Some values aren't considered Truthy just because they exist (or have something in it). You are passing an `Index` which does not behave like you expect for `if categories...`. Try `if categories != None and ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing a value which doesn't support conversion to a `bool`. In this case, you need to explicitly check if the value is not `None`:

```
if categories is not None:
```

Answer (score 7):

I suggest this:

```
def load_data(datafile, categories=None, cat_columns=None):
    ohe_categories = 'auto'
    if categories is not None:
        if len(categories) > 0:
            ohe_categories = categories
    ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', categories=ohe_categories)
```